# How many ways to arrange 9 children and 5 adults in 7 pairs

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

how many ways to arrange $9$ children and $5$ adults in $7$ pairs such that :

$2$ pairs has (child,child)

$5$ pairs has (child,adult)

note : the arrangement ($1$ child , $1$ adult ) = ( $1$ adult , $1$ child)

how one solve this question through $(_n^{k})$ which means arranging $n$ from $k$
or am i missing something ?

I know the first 2 pairs should have $(_2^{9})$$(_2^{7})$

**final answer : 45360**

Comment: The notation $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways of selecting a subset of $k$ elements from a set with $n$ elements.

Comment: true but how you choose diffrent elements subset from a set , (1 adult , child ) from (5 children , 5 adults )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose which four of the nine children will not be paired with an adult.  Choose which of the other three children will be paired with the youngest child.  The other two children must form the other pair of children.  This can be done in
$$\binom{9}{4}\binom{3}{1}$$
ways.

Line up the five adults in some order, say alphabetically by name. Choose which of the five remaining children will be matched with the first adult, which of the four remaining children will be matched with the second adult, which of the three remaining children will be matched with the third adult, and which of the two remaining children will be matched with the fourth adult.  The final child must be matched with the fifth adult.  This can be done in $5!$ ways.

Hence, there are 
$$\binom{9}{4}\binom{3}{1}5!$$
ways to place nine children and five adults in seven pairs such that two pairs each contain two children and five pairs each contain one adult and one child.